# Как в Laravel узнать какой table заденет команда php artisan migrate:rollback?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть база данных, после команды `php artisan migrate:rollback`  изменился не тот table который был  нужен.

Можно ли как-то узнать, кокой table заденет команда `migrate:rollback`, до ее выполнения ?

Comment: зайти в папку с миграциями и посмотреть?

Comment: @Manitikyl просмотр папки может привести к ошибке так-как  не обязательно что последняя миграция в папке  будет объектом `migrate:rollback` (например  в папке есть  новый table  который еще не зарегистрирован  ты делаешь  migrate:rollback  надеешься  что будет rollback  последнего , а  rollback   делается для предпоследнего) таких примеров много , `migrate : status`  не сильно поможет нужно  что-то вроде команды `migrate : rollbackStatus`  или возможность выбирать  table              (например, `migrate : rollback   --table="my_second_table" `)

Comment: А найти код, который запускает миграцию и отладиться? На худой конец, поднять копию БД, включить general_log и запустить.

Comment: я, если честно, не совсем вас понял. У вашего проекта есть определенный `id-миграции`, вы можете его посмотреть, зная его легко определить что в папке было выполнено, что нет. По поводу конкретного выбора: Вы не понимаете для чего нужны миграции.

Comment: Суть миграций - не тыкать в определенную табличку, откатывая или накатывая ее, и даже не играться с файлами. Она используется в связке с файлами. Т.е. у вас есть сайт. Чтоб грамотно им управлять - используются ПО для `непрерывной интеграции`. Они состоят из `системы контроля версии` и кучу других плюх. Вот вы пишете новый патч который затрагивает БД, пишите миграцию загружаете в SVN. Потом в этом ПО вы кликаете мол: залить на продашкн. И вот ВМЕСТЕ с файлами и миграцией происходит накат. Потом вы поняли что ваш патч кривой, вы кликаете: откатить: и ВМЕСТЕ с файлами и миграцией происходит откат

Comment: Задите в таблице в БД migrates посмотрите номера выполнений, какой самый вернхний тот и заденится, если нужно изменить порядок, или что б откатить ток одну таблицу поменяйте соответственно номера